# How to get "Dans" in place of "IN" in bibliography latex

Tags: bibliographies, french

I am writing my thesis in french and I need to put bibliography in french.
I am using this style `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-fr}`.

```
@inproceedings{ref1,
  title={Learning from Synthetic Data Using a Stacked Multichannel Autoencoder},
  author={Zhang, Xi and Fu, Yanwei and Jiang, Shanshan and Sigal, Leonid and Agam, Gady},
  booktitle={2015 IEEE 14th International Conference on Machine Learning and Applications (ICMLA)},
  pages={461--464},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

[image]

Instead of *"IN 2015 IEEE...."* I need to get the french version (may be "*Dans 2015 IEEE....*")
I have used this option but it generate an error *Undefined control sequence*  \selectbiblanguage:

```
\selectbiblanguage{french}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the term `in` used in bibliographies is not an English term, but a Latin one, and it's also used in French.

Comment: Try `\renewbibmacro{in:}{dans:}` in your preamble.

Comment: More exactly, `\renewbibmacro{in:}{\printtext{\bibstring{dans}\intitlepunct}}`, but I ddon't recommend it.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-fr}` strongly suggests you are not using `bibilatex` at all. Yet you have tagged your question with it. Note that both suggestions you got in the comments assume you use `biblatex`. I have removed the tag to avoid confusion. But please check exactly what system you are using. You can make your chances of getting an answer greater by providing a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).